# Por que sintaxe C funciona para criar limite variável de range em bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Eu tentei criar um limite variável em um range para um for loop em bash usando uma função. Segue meu código:

```bsh
function tree(){
    let var=$1
    for i in {1..$var}
    do
        echo $i
    done
}

tree 5
```

Para minha frustração, isso imprime `{1..5}` em vez de

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Descobri que consigo resolver esse problema usando uma sintaxe parecida com C:

```bsh
function tree(){
    let var=$1
    for ((i=1;i<$var;i++))
    do
        echo $i
    done
}
tree 6
```

Minha pergunta é, por que a sintaxe C funciona para esse caso e bash puro não funciona? Além disso, é sempre possível usar sintaxe C em bash?

Comment: Pergunta muito interessante Lucas! Quero acompanhar se alguém sabe! Fiquei curioso! ótima semana. Se descobrir, coloque a resposta aqui para nós.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você consultar o manual do Bash (digitando `man bash` no seu terminal, ou lendo a [versão online](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)), verá o seguinte:

> *Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions, and **any characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result**. It is strictly textual. Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation to the context of the expansion or the text between the braces.*

Ou seja, colocar variáveis como você fez (`{1..$var}`) não funciona mesmo, pois neste caso o `$var` não é interpretado como uma variável.

Então uma solução seria usar o `for`, como você fez. Apenas para citar outras alternativas de solução:

```
# usando "seq"
function tree(){
    let var=$1
    for i in $(seq 1 $var)
    do
        echo $i
    done
}

# ou ainda (esta é mais portável, pois "seq" nem sempre pode estar disponível)
function tree(){
    let var=$1
    i=1
    while [ $i -le $var ]; do
        echo $i
        i=$(($i+1))
    done
}
```

---

Quanto à "sintaxe do C", na verdade não é *bem* assim. No mesmo [manual já citado](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), na seção "*Compound Commands*", tem isso:

> `for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do list ; done`
> *First, the arithmetic expression expr1 is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION. The arithmetic expression expr2 is then evaluated repeatedly until it evaluates to zero. Each time expr2 evaluates to a non-zero value, list is executed and the arithmetic expression expr3 is evaluated. If any expression is omitted, it behaves as if it evaluates to 1. The return value is the exit status of the last command in list that is executed, or false if any of the expressions is invalid.*

Ou seja, esse `for` é uma construção definida pelo Bash, então você não está usando "sintaxe C", e sim uma sintaxe que o Bash definiu. **Claro** que é muito similar à sintaxe do C (inspirada? copiada?), mas isso é circunstancial (não sei se foi "sem querer" ou proposital, mas de qualquer forma não é C, ainda é Bash).

Se eu tivesse que chutar, diria que aconteceu algo relativamente comum, que é quando uma linguagem adota uma sintaxe similar (quando não igual) à de outra (como [muitas outras linguagens fazem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-family_programming_languages) ao adotar sintaxes similares ou até idênticas ao C).

Mas isso não quer dizer que qualquer sintaxe válida em C pode ser usada no Bash. Algumas coisas que o Bash definiu *podem* ser parecidas ou idênticas a outras linguagens, mas ainda sim você deve consultar sempre o manual da linguagem que está usando, em vez de pensar "*parece C, deve funcionar igual*" (às vezes sim, às vezes não).